# ChromeDriver and Chrome Browser out of sync

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, zalenium

Recently Chrome got updated to version 79. I've updated chromedriver to the respective version same way as I always do - inside my java project. But when I deploy Zalenium, in containers, inside home/seluser/ there's still chromedriver-78. I've tried deleting that old chromedriver with 'kubectl rm chromedriver' - file is getting deleted bu I'm not able to run any tests. I've tried redeploying Zalenium and no luck. Everything is timestamped with the latest date except the chromedriver file. Never had this issue in the past of course.
How do I update chromedriver so that is updated across all containers?
How does Zalenium control/handle Chrome browser updates?

Here's the chromedriver insde a container whenever I use 'Interact via VNC':
[image: home/seluser]

Here's the code snippet with how I handle accessing the chromedriver:

```
public static MutableCapabilities getChromeCapability() {
    String chromePath = prop_conf_browsers.getProperty("chromePath");
    String chromeDriverPath = prop_conf_browsers.getProperty("chromeDriverPath");
    System.out.println(chromeDriverPath);
    String chromeProfileDir = prop_conf_browsers.getProperty("chromeProfileDir");
    if (chromePath != null && !chromePath.equalsIgnoreCase("default") && !chromePath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.bin", chromePath);
    }
    if (chromeDriverPath != null && !chromeDriverPath.equalsIgnoreCase("default")
            && !chromeDriverPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
    }
```

Environment info:

```
capabilities: Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, maxInstances: 1, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, resolution: 1920x1080, screen-resolution: 1920x1080, screenResolution: 1920x1080, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: 456a4fcc-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx..., tz: America/Chicago, version: 79.0.3945.79}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to configure ChromeDriver in you Java project, the docker containers already have all this configured.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. If docker containers have that configured already that's even better! The question remains how do I get Chrome browser and Chromedriver in sync? Is there something on my end I need to do?

Comment: Chromedriver and ChromeBrowser were out of sync. The issue was addressed in this commit:
https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/commit/90a9c65031341d204d52c3d06ac02a0958c64079